# How to take screenshot alway has the same date and time?

Tags: ios

I barely remember when taking a screenshot earlier in a simulator the date-time is always the same at `09:41 Sat Sep 12`. However, when I try to take screenshots with the iOS simulator it's actually using the system time.

For a consistent preview experience, how to take screenshots always have the same date and time?

Comment: Found this online, https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic

Comment: ... or just do `xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "9:41" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100`

Answer (score 1):

- Clone this repository.
- Open SimulatorStatusMagic.xcodeproj with Xcode 6 (or above)
- Run the app target SimulatorStatusMagic

https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic

[image]